# Under what conditions does GNU Make change the stack size, and why?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, ulimit

Consider this makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

all: dummy test
    ulimit -s

include dummy

dummy: test
    touch dummy
```

When I run it, I get:

```
$ make -v
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$ touch test; make
touch dummy
ulimit -s
unlimited
```

However, if I remove the `include dummy` or replace `touch dummy` with `true`, then `ulimit -s` gives `8192`.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [bug 48009](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?48009) which was fixed in GNU make 4.2.1.